# "Cannot convert from decimal to double"

Tags: double, decimal

I'm trying to pull some numbers that occur in my database as fractions of a day in decimal format. These times can be null in some circumstances though, so I am trying to utilize this method to account for it but am getting build errors in my application, namel:

> "The best overloaded method match for "system.TimeSpan.FromDays(double)' has some invalid arguments"

and

> "Argument1:cannot convert from 'decimal' to 'double'".

Is there a method for this I am missing?

```
time1 = reader.IsDBNull(4) ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.FromDays(reader.GetDecimal(4)),
time2 = reader.IsDBNull(5) ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.FromDays(reader.GetDecimal(5)),
time3 = reader.IsDBNull(6) ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.FromDays(reader.GetDecimal(6)),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `decimal` cannot be implicitly converted to `double`.  You can explicitly cast it:

```
time1 = 
    reader.IsDBNull(4) ? 
    TimeSpan.Zero : 
    TimeSpan.FromDays((double)reader.GetDecimal(4))
```

Decimal is an unusual choice for a DB type representing a count of days.  I suggest you ensure that the column really does represent that.

Comment: Turns out there was something wrong with my query, I wasn't doing a left join I needed. But thanks for the explicit double cast method.